# Accessing Hadoop from Python -- java.io.IOException: The pipe has been ended

Tags: java, python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to run a mapper reducer job in Windows 10 using hadoop. I am getting the following error. I have looked everywhere but cannot find a solution. Basically `java.io.IOException: The pipe has been ended`

#### What I did?

1. added shebanger line
2. changed `-mapper mapper.py` to `-mapper "python <full path to mapper>"`
3. checked the mapper and reducer code, all the config files (XML files)
4. added the mapper and reducer to the same folder as input file in the hadoop fs

None of the above solutions worked.

```
2020-10-21 01:52:36,861 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: Loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2020-10-21 01:52:37,002 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2020-10-21 01:52:37,002 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobTracker metrics system started
2020-10-21 01:52:37,028 WARN impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobTracker metrics system already initialized!
2020-10-21 01:52:37,964 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2020-10-21 01:52:38,209 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
2020-10-21 01:52:38,386 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local105213688_0001
2020-10-21 01:52:38,387 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2020-10-21 01:52:38,557 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
2020-10-21 01:52:38,561 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local105213688_0001
2020-10-21 01:52:38,561 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
2020-10-21 01:52:38,566 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter
2020-10-21 01:52:38,579 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
2020-10-21 01:52:38,579 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2020-10-21 01:52:38,689 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
2020-10-21 01:52:38,694 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local105213688_0001_m_000000_0
2020-10-21 01:52:38,732 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2
2020-10-21 01:52:38,733 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false
2020-10-21 01:52:38,745 INFO util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: ProcfsBasedProcessTree currently is supported only on Linux.
2020-10-21 01:52:38,801 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.WindowsBasedProcessTree@6b965617
2020-10-21 01:52:38,820 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:9000/inp/inputfile.txt:0+6488666
2020-10-21 01:52:38,883 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
2020-10-21 01:52:39,001 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
2020-10-21 01:52:39,001 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
2020-10-21 01:52:39,003 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
2020-10-21 01:52:39,004 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
2020-10-21 01:52:39,005 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
2020-10-21 01:52:39,012 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
2020-10-21 01:52:39,115 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed exec [D:\Wireshark\uninstall.exe, D:\ll\sem5\Cloud_Computing\assignment\lab6-7\lab7\mapper.py]
2020-10-21 01:52:39,127 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.work.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.output.dir
2020-10-21 01:52:39,129 INFO Configuration.deprecation: map.input.start is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.start
2020-10-21 01:52:39,130 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.is.map is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.ismap
2020-10-21 01:52:39,131 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
2020-10-21 01:52:39,133 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id
2020-10-21 01:52:39,137 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.local.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.cluster.local.dir
2020-10-21 01:52:39,138 INFO Configuration.deprecation: map.input.file is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.file
2020-10-21 01:52:39,140 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.on is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.skiprecords
2020-10-21 01:52:39,141 INFO Configuration.deprecation: map.input.length is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.input.length
2020-10-21 01:52:39,143 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
2020-10-21 01:52:39,144 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
2020-10-21 01:52:39,147 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.partition
2020-10-21 01:52:39,470 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=1/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
2020-10-21 01:52:39,471 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=10/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
2020-10-21 01:52:39,474 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=100/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
2020-10-21 01:52:39,481 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=1000/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
2020-10-21 01:52:39,584 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local105213688_0001 running in uber mode : false
2020-10-21 01:52:39,586 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2020-10-21 01:52:40,423 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: MRErrorThread done
2020-10-21 01:52:40,425 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=1299/0/0 in:1299=1299/1 [rec/s] out:0=0/1 [rec/s]
minRecWrittenToEnableSkip_=9223372036854775807 HOST=null
USER=null
HADOOP_USER=null
last tool output: |null|

java.io.IOException: The pipe has been ended
       at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
       at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:348)
       at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
       at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
       at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:127)
       at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeUTF8(TextInputWriter.java:72)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeValue(TextInputWriter.java:51)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:106)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:271)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
2020-10-21 01:52:40,431 WARN streaming.PipeMapRed: {}
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
       at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
       at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:348)
       at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
       at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
       at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
       at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:532)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:120)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:271)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
2020-10-21 01:52:40,433 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: mapRedFinished
2020-10-21 01:52:40,435 WARN streaming.PipeMapRed: {}
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
       at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
       at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:348)
       at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
       at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
       at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
       at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:532)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:271)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
2020-10-21 01:52:40,438 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: mapRedFinished
2020-10-21 01:52:40,445 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
2020-10-21 01:52:40,506 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local105213688_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: The pipe has been ended
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:492)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:552)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The pipe has been ended
       at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
       at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:348)
       at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
       at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
       at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:127)
       at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeUTF8(TextInputWriter.java:72)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeValue(TextInputWriter.java:51)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:106)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:271)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
2020-10-21 01:52:40,596 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local105213688_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
2020-10-21 01:52:40,625 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
2020-10-21 01:52:40,625 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful!
Streaming Command Failed!
```

#### Input File

```
Over the years, there have been many releases of PowerShell. Initially, Windows PowerShell was built on the .NET Framework and only worked on Windows systems. With the current release, PowerShell uses .NET Core 3.1 as its runtime. PowerShell runs on Windows, macOS, and Linux platforms.
```

#### My Python code

MAPPER

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
d={}
for line in sys.stdin:
    line= line.strip()
    words=line.split()
    for word in words:
```

REDUCER

```
import sys
cur_word= None
cur_cnt=0

for line in sys.stdin:
    line=line.strip().split(',')
    # print(line)
    word, count= line[0], (int)(line[1])

    if cur_word==None:
        cur_word=word
        cur_cnt=count
    elif cur_word==word:
        cur_cnt+=count
    else:
        print(cur_word,',', cur_cnt)
        cur_word=word
        cur_cnt=count
print(cur_word,",",count)
```

I have done everything but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapper seems incomplete: it is missing `print word`